# Unable to Recover Corrupt Oracle Datafile Block In SysAux

Tags: database, oracle, backup, recover, rman

Oracle 10g on Suse 9.1

I'm looking after an Oracle DB. I have good SQL skills but I'm no DBA, (a diffence in job roles I have difficulty explaining to my non-IT savvy bosses!) I know enough to get Oracle up and running and put in place it's 'automatic' options for backup and optimisation then I leave it well alone. Everything else I know from the university of Google!

I recently discovered that our production DB has not been running it's daily backups. It had started one that then hung and didn't report any problems so it was not noticed right away. (The backup job hung, not the oracle instance.)

I have killed the backup, (it got stuck in stop pending so I had to force it out in the end), and I want to get a new backup schedule running, but at the moment I am getting a corrupt block warning. I've tried using blockrecover to fix it but I get RMAN-06023: no backup or copy of datafile found to restore. Running a crosscheck says files are available.

The corrupt block is in the SYSAUX tablespace datafile. If I take the DB offline can I drop and recreate this datafile or will that corrupt the DB? (I'm way to nervous to take the DB offline at the moment as I don't know if it'll come back up!)

Thanks for your help. Below is the output from my recover attempt...

```
//#### OUTPUT FROM EM - Trying to get EM to recover corrupt block.
Recovery Manager: Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on Fri Sep 25 10:39:44 2009

Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

RMAN> 
connected to target database: PROD (DBID=1370345313)
using target database control file instead of recovery catalog

RMAN> 
echo set on


RMAN> run {
2> blockrecover corruption list;
3> backup validate datafile 3;
4> }
Starting blockrecover at 25-SEP-09
allocated channel: ORA_DISK_1
channel ORA_DISK_1: sid=141 devtype=DISK

channel ORA_DISK_1: restoring block(s) from datafile copy /u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/datafile/o1_mf_sysaux_315toql6_.dbf
failover to previous backup

channel ORA_DISK_1: restoring block(s) from datafile copy /u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/datafile/o1_mf_sysaux_4smgtz57_.dbf
failover to previous backup

RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-03002: failure of blockrecover command at 09/25/2009 10:39:51
RMAN-06026: some targets not found - aborting restore
RMAN-06023: no backup or copy of datafile 3 found to restore


RMAN> exit;

Recovery Manager complete.
//#### END OF OUTPUT FROM EM


RMAN> crosscheck backup of datafile 3;

allocated channel: ORA_DISK_1
channel ORA_DISK_1: sid=141 devtype=DISK
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_01_13/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090113T000027_4pqpdwh3_.bkp recid=1190 stamp=675993628
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_01_14/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090114T000038_4ptbs6v1_.bkp recid=1192 stamp=676080038
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_01_15/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090115T000038_4pwz56z2_.bkp recid=1194 stamp=676166438
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_01_16/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090116T000036_4pzmk58b_.bkp recid=1196 stamp=676252837
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_01_17/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090117T000037_4q27x6rw_.bkp recid=1198 stamp=676339238
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_01_18/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090118T000035_4q4w94b0_.bkp recid=1200 stamp=676425636
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_01_19/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090119T000026_4q7jntpx_.bkp recid=1202 stamp=676512026
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_01_20/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090120T000026_4qb50vbq_.bkp recid=1204 stamp=676598427
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_01_21/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090121T000034_4qdsf38g_.bkp recid=1206 stamp=676684835
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_01_22/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090122T000039_4qhfs86z_.bkp recid=1208 stamp=676771240
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_01_23/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090123T000037_4ql255no_.bkp recid=1210 stamp=676857637
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_01_24/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090124T000034_4qnpk3ls_.bkp recid=1212 stamp=676944035
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_01_25/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090125T000036_4qqbx5l8_.bkp recid=1214 stamp=677030437
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_01_26/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090126T000025_4qsz8vdv_.bkp recid=1216 stamp=677116826
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_01_27/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090127T000031_4qwmo0jz_.bkp recid=1218 stamp=677203232
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_01_28/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090128T000038_4qz817jg_.bkp recid=1220 stamp=677289639
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_01_29/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090129T000127_4r1wgrd1_.bkp recid=1222 stamp=677376088
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_01_30/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090130T000035_4r4js4g5_.bkp recid=1224 stamp=677462436
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_01_31/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090131T000035_4r75549f_.bkp recid=1226 stamp=677548836
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_02_01/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090201T000036_4r9sk56m_.bkp recid=1228 stamp=677635237
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_02_02/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090202T000027_4rdfwwo7_.bkp recid=1230 stamp=677721628
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_02_03/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090203T000027_4rh28w5o_.bkp recid=1232 stamp=677808027
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_02_04/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090204T000036_4rkpo4rw_.bkp recid=1234 stamp=677894436
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_02_05/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090205T000038_4rnc16w7_.bkp recid=1236 stamp=677980838
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_02_06/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090206T000035_4rpzf429_.bkp recid=1238 stamp=678067235
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_02_07/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090207T000036_4rsms5dp_.bkp recid=1240 stamp=678153637
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_02_08/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090208T000036_4rw854xz_.bkp recid=1242 stamp=678240036
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_02_09/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090209T000025_4rywjtlq_.bkp recid=1244 stamp=678326426
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_02_10/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090210T000029_4s1jwyj0_.bkp recid=1246 stamp=678412830
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_02_11/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090211T000035_4s4593qo_.bkp recid=1248 stamp=678499235
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_02_12/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090212T000036_4s6so57f_.bkp recid=1250 stamp=678585637
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_02_13/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090213T000037_4s9g15yk_.bkp recid=1252 stamp=678672037
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_02_14/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090214T000035_4sd2f4k9_.bkp recid=1254 stamp=678758436
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_02_15/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090215T000037_4sgps5tz_.bkp recid=1256 stamp=678844837
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_02_16/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090216T000028_4skc4x95_.bkp recid=1258 stamp=678931229
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_02_17/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090217T020032_4sn6l179_.bkp recid=1262 stamp=679024833
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_02_18/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090218T020037_4spty6cn_.bkp recid=1264 stamp=679111238
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_02_19/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090219T020034_4sshb3jm_.bkp recid=1266 stamp=679197635
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_02_20/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090220T020037_4sw3p66r_.bkp recid=1268 stamp=679284038
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_02_21/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090221T020036_4syr25hw_.bkp recid=1270 stamp=679370437
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_02_22/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090222T020033_4t1dg1xm_.bkp recid=1272 stamp=679456833
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_02_23/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090223T020027_4t40svx9_.bkp recid=1274 stamp=679543227
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_02_24/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090224T020025_4t6o5tcz_.bkp recid=1276 stamp=679629626
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_02_25/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090225T020038_4t99l6py_.bkp recid=1278 stamp=679716038
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_02_26/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090226T020037_4tcxy6hg_.bkp recid=1280 stamp=679802438
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_02_27/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090227T020037_4tglb6qw_.bkp recid=1282 stamp=679888838
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_03_02/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090302T104414_4tqg3zb2_.bkp recid=1284 stamp=680438655
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_03_03/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090303T020033_4ts3t2o7_.bkp recid=1286 stamp=680493634
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_03_04/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090304T020032_4tvr60yq_.bkp recid=1288 stamp=680580032
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_03_05/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090305T020032_4tydl1hs_.bkp recid=1290 stamp=680666433
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_03_06/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090306T020034_4v10y2xk_.bkp recid=1292 stamp=680752834
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_03_07/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090307T020036_4v3ob5hr_.bkp recid=1294 stamp=680839237
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_03_08/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090308T020038_4v69p729_.bkp recid=1296 stamp=680925638
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_03_09/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090309T020026_4v8y1vyj_.bkp recid=1298 stamp=681012027
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_03_10/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090310T020027_4vclfw5s_.bkp recid=1300 stamp=681098427
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_03_11/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090311T020037_4vg6t6d8_.bkp recid=1302 stamp=681184838
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_03_12/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090312T020035_4vjv64pv_.bkp recid=1304 stamp=681271236
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_03_13/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090313T020036_4vmhl54t_.bkp recid=1306 stamp=681357637
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_03_14/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090314T020038_4vp3y6sn_.bkp recid=1308 stamp=681444038
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_03_15/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090315T020038_4vrrb736_.bkp recid=1310 stamp=681530439
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_03_16/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090316T020024_4vvdosv2_.bkp recid=1312 stamp=681616825
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_03_17/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090317T020026_4vy11tsn_.bkp recid=1314 stamp=681703226
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_03_18/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090318T020034_4w0og2p4_.bkp recid=1316 stamp=681789634
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_03_19/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090319T020034_4w39t39g_.bkp recid=1318 stamp=681876034
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_03_20/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090320T020035_4w5y6458_.bkp recid=1320 stamp=681962436
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_03_21/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090321T020034_4w8ll2s8_.bkp recid=1322 stamp=682048834
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_03_22/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090322T020034_4wc6y380_.bkp recid=1324 stamp=682135235
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_03_23/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090323T020026_4wfv9v2r_.bkp recid=1326 stamp=682221626
crosschecked backup piece: found to be 'AVAILABLE'
backup piece handle=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/flash_recovery_area/PROD/backupset/2009_03_24/o1_mf_nnnd1_TAG20090324T020025_4wjhothw_.bkp recid=1328 stamp=682308026
Crosschecked 69 objects


RMAN> list expired backup of datafile 3;


RMAN> list backup of datafile 3 summary;


List of Backups
===============
Key     TY LV S Device Type Completion Time #Pieces #Copies Compressed Tag
------- -- -- - ----------- --------------- ------- ------- ---------- ---
1190    B  1  A DISK        13-JAN-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090113T000027
1192    B  1  A DISK        14-JAN-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090114T000038
1194    B  1  A DISK        15-JAN-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090115T000038
1196    B  1  A DISK        16-JAN-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090116T000036
1198    B  1  A DISK        17-JAN-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090117T000037
1200    B  1  A DISK        18-JAN-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090118T000035
1202    B  1  A DISK        19-JAN-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090119T000026
1204    B  1  A DISK        20-JAN-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090120T000026
1206    B  1  A DISK        21-JAN-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090121T000034
1208    B  1  A DISK        22-JAN-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090122T000039
1210    B  1  A DISK        23-JAN-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090123T000037
1212    B  1  A DISK        24-JAN-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090124T000034
1214    B  1  A DISK        25-JAN-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090125T000036
1216    B  1  A DISK        26-JAN-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090126T000025
1218    B  1  A DISK        27-JAN-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090127T000031
1220    B  1  A DISK        28-JAN-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090128T000038
1222    B  1  A DISK        29-JAN-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090129T000127
1224    B  1  A DISK        30-JAN-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090130T000035
1226    B  1  A DISK        31-JAN-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090131T000035
1228    B  1  A DISK        01-FEB-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090201T000036
1230    B  1  A DISK        02-FEB-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090202T000027
1232    B  1  A DISK        03-FEB-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090203T000027
1234    B  1  A DISK        04-FEB-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090204T000036
1236    B  1  A DISK        05-FEB-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090205T000038
1238    B  1  A DISK        06-FEB-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090206T000035
1240    B  1  A DISK        07-FEB-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090207T000036
1242    B  1  A DISK        08-FEB-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090208T000036
1244    B  1  A DISK        09-FEB-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090209T000025
1246    B  1  A DISK        10-FEB-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090210T000029
1248    B  1  A DISK        11-FEB-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090211T000035
1250    B  1  A DISK        12-FEB-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090212T000036
1252    B  1  A DISK        13-FEB-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090213T000037
1254    B  1  A DISK        14-FEB-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090214T000035
1256    B  1  A DISK        15-FEB-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090215T000037
1258    B  1  A DISK        16-FEB-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090216T000028
1262    B  1  A DISK        17-FEB-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090217T020032
1264    B  1  A DISK        18-FEB-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090218T020037
1266    B  1  A DISK        19-FEB-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090219T020034
1268    B  1  A DISK        20-FEB-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090220T020037
1270    B  1  A DISK        21-FEB-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090221T020036
1272    B  1  A DISK        22-FEB-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090222T020033
1274    B  1  A DISK        23-FEB-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090223T020027
1276    B  1  A DISK        24-FEB-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090224T020025
1278    B  1  A DISK        25-FEB-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090225T020038
1280    B  1  A DISK        26-FEB-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090226T020037
1282    B  1  A DISK        27-FEB-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090227T020037
1284    B  1  A DISK        02-MAR-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090302T104414
1286    B  1  A DISK        03-MAR-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090303T020033
1288    B  1  A DISK        04-MAR-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090304T020032
1290    B  1  A DISK        05-MAR-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090305T020032
1292    B  1  A DISK        06-MAR-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090306T020034
1294    B  1  A DISK        07-MAR-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090307T020036
1296    B  1  A DISK        08-MAR-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090308T020038
1298    B  1  A DISK        09-MAR-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090309T020026
1300    B  1  A DISK        10-MAR-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090310T020027
1302    B  1  A DISK        11-MAR-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090311T020037
1304    B  1  A DISK        12-MAR-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090312T020035
1306    B  1  A DISK        13-MAR-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090313T020036
1308    B  1  A DISK        14-MAR-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090314T020038
1310    B  1  A DISK        15-MAR-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090315T020038
1312    B  1  A DISK        16-MAR-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090316T020024
1314    B  1  A DISK        17-MAR-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090317T020026
1316    B  1  A DISK        18-MAR-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090318T020034
1318    B  1  A DISK        19-MAR-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090319T020034
1320    B  1  A DISK        20-MAR-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090320T020035
1322    B  1  A DISK        21-MAR-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090321T020034
1324    B  1  A DISK        22-MAR-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090322T020034
1326    B  1  A DISK        23-MAR-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090323T020026
1328    B  1  A DISK        24-MAR-09       1       1       NO         TAG20090324T020025

RMAN>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the completion times.  You have a file for every day from 13-JAN-09 until the 24-MAR-09.  Since then, nada.  So what RMAN is telling is that it cannot find any backups of datafile 3 for the last six months.

Don't panic.

How big is your database?  Is it feasible to do an export?   There may be a simpler solution, but if you can get your data out you have the option to recreate the database.

**edit**

According to [the documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9004.htm) it is possible to drop the SYSAUX tablespace.  Details to follow.

**edit 2**

Dropping and re-creating SYSAUX tablespace is not for the faint-hearted.  I confess that this is the first time I have attempted it.  Right now I am stymied by this:

```
SQL> drop tablespace sysaux including contents and datafiles
  2  /
drop tablespace sysaux including contents and datafiles
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-29857: domain indexes and/or secondary objects exist in the tablespace


SQL> drop index xdb.xdb$acl_xidx force;
drop index xdb.xdb$acl_xidx force
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-29868: cannot issue DDL on a domain index marked as LOADING


SQL>
```

This is a road block.  `DROP INDEX FORCE` is supposed to be the workaround for ORA-29868, so I'm non-plussed to see that message.  Anyway, once I get beyond this hill I expect there will be others.  It don't think it's a tidy process.  But then, to be fair, it's not something we're meant to be doing at all.

So, it's good news that you can do an export, because I very much fear that recreating the database is your best bet.  Good luck.

Oh, and once you've sorted this situation out, impress upon your bosses the urgency of hiring a DBA (or getting you properly trained, if that is what you would like).

Finally, this is a very good teaching for you.  The first time I had to do a restore I discovered the previous DBA had not enabled `ARCHIVELOG` mode, and I hadn't checked.  My punishment was to visit all the users and inform them they had lost a day's work.  The moral is, *a backup which has not been tested does not exist*.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.

I'm not panicking....yet ;o)

Database is definitely small enough to export. In fact that's what I'm using at the moment so we have something in the way of a backup until I get the auto backups working again.

Sounds like I'm going to have to recreate the database though - not ideal but anything is better than data loss!

Comment: Thank you for putting so much effort into your reply APC. Recreating the database sounds like the best option. Time to start making sure I've got everything in place to do it...

Answer (score 1):

Your latest backup of datafile 3 is from 24-MAR-09. I don't think you have enough archive to recover the datafile to 25 SEP 09.
As far as I know you can not drop and recreate the SYSAUX tablespace. It contains data related to options and features such as OLAP, Text, Ultra Search, Intermedia, Spatial, Workspace, Data Mining, EM Repository, Streams, LogMiner, Logical Standby, Statspack, Job Scheduler.
If you have Oracle support I would get help from them.
I would try to do an export or expdp as soon as possible of the appication schema's. 
To get some kind of data backup, I suspect you have no recoverable backup at the moment.

And I forgot, APC is right : don't panic.